# User P_FSSUserffffffff and S_FSSUserffffffff on all Windows Service Fabric nodes

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In my computer management console I can see two users `P_FSSUserffffffff` and `S_FSSUserffffffff` and they are in group `FSSGroupffffffff`.
There are also some more groups starting with WF-App following some random numbers. For example `WF-App-4294967295-c983f0a0ccb3235a199072e7538a3bb4`.

Seriously. **Any documentation on that?**
Does Service Fabric rely on these users?

Answer (score 0):

Those two accounts (S_FSSUserffffffff and P_FSSUserffffffff) are used to ACL shares used by ImageStore to copy files securely between nodes.

https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/153